# Illustrator: How to select a colour range

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, color-management, color-separation

You know how you can select individual colours? And you can go to the `select` menu, and click `select fill`?

I need to do that but for a colour range.

Say for instance, you trace a photograph and expand it, and you want to remove a red stamp from the image (the expanded trace). You can select a red bit, and `select`, `select fill`, <kbd>delete</kbd>, or paint transparent, or set opacity to 0%, but you're still left with bits and pieces of different shades of pinks and reds.

You can sometimes just reduce the complexity of the trace so there's fewer colours or whatever, but that distorts the whole image.

I've tried just selecting a range of colours simultaneously by holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and clicking objects with the selection (<kbd>U</kbd>) tool. but it didn't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Magic Wand Tool** like in Photoshop and click on ungrouped shapes.

> **[Magic Wand tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html)**: Lets you select objects of the same color, stroke weight, stroke color, opacity, or blending mode by clicking the object.

- Double click the **Magic Wand Tool** to change the options

  - Activate only *Fill Color*
  - Try with different *Tolerance*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've never actually used Photoshop, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: wait is there a magic wand now in Illustrator? hmm time to upgrade from CS6...

Comment: @Luciano - yes!  A surprise to me too, and I use CC,but  never even noticed it before.  You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

In case the magic wand tolerance simply isn't working for you, you can do this how it was done before that tool/panel was added....

## What you can do....

- Using the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow), select something filled with the color you want to keep and create a **swatch** of that color.
- Still with the Direct Selection Tool, select a color you want to *remove*.
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` from the menu.
- Use the swatch you created and change the fill/stroke to that *same color*.
- Repeat for every color you want to remove.

When you have changed all the unwanted colors to your desired color, you can combine the art...

- Select all
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

This will combine all areas of the same fill.

Be aware, if you have "hollow" objects - object which have no fill and no stroke -- you will need to remove those before using the Merge command. The easiest way to do that is to draw a rectangle with no fill and no stroke and then choose `Select > Same > Fill & stroke` from the menu and hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.